# How do I hide/show a div container within an unordered list so it replaces the inline list element

Tags: jquery, list, html, hide, show

**Before I begin, you should know there's a lot of information here. This one because I can't post pix yet, and two so we don't waste each other's time. All help I receive on this post is greatly appreciated!**

So I'm working with an unordered list, where the list elements are displayed as inline in large text. The list itself takes up about 80% of the page.

When you click a list element, a div should pop up to replace the list element explaining what the list element means, and if you click the div, the div disappears and the list element reappears.

The problem I'm running into is that I want the div elements to replace the list element exactly how it's placed (margins and everything) in the unordered list. Instead what's happening is the div appears on the left everytime, and the unordered list elements get rearranged on the right.

**Here's the html:**

```
    <div id="bottom">
    <h1 class="issue_line">So what's the issue in Niagara Falls?</h1>
    <ul class="issue_headings">
    <li class="issue1">Education</li>
 <div class="quarter-box1">
  <p>The members of NOAH recognize that <strong>quality education</strong> is      
      necessary for any community to thrive...<br/>
  <a href="issues_taskforces.html">Read more.</a></p>
 </div>

    <li class="issue2">Local Hiring</li>
 <div class="quarter-box2">
  <p>The need for jobs in Niagara County is overwhelming, and NOAH is working to 
      create more local jobs through the policy level...<br/>
  <a href="issues_taskforces.html">Read more.</a></p>
 </div>

    <li class="issue3">Economic Development</li>
 <div class="quarter-box3">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et   
      facilisis risus. Quisque a gravida urna. Ut leo ligula...<br/>
 <a href="issues_taskforces.html">Read more.</a></p>
 </div>

    <li class="issue4">Trasnportation</li>
 <div class="quarter-box4">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et 
     facilisis risus. Quisque a gravida urna. Ut leo ligula...<br/>
 <a href="issues_taskforces.html">Read more.</a></p>
</div>

    </ul>
    </div>
```

**Here's the CSS**

```
     #bottom {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto; 
      clear: both;
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
     }

     ul.issue_headings {
      width: 1498px;
      float: left;
      margin-top: 50px;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      padding: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      display: none;
      text-align: center;
     }

     ul.issue_headings li {
      display: inline;
      margin-left: 2%;
      padding: 0;
      font-size: 3em;
      color: #9ac0e2;
     }

     ul.issue_headings li:hover {
      color: #FF9933;
     }

     .quarter-box1 { 
      float: left;
      margin-left: 50px;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
      border: 3px solid #0c69bf;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px black;
      width: 280px;
      height: 150px;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: none;
     }

     .quarter-box2 { 
      float: left;
      margin-left: 100px;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
      border: 3px solid #0c69bf;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px black;
      width: 280px;
      height: 150px;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: none;
     }

     .quarter-box3 {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 150px;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
      border: 3px solid #0c69bf;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px black;
      width: 280px;
      height: 150px;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: none;
     } 

     .quarter-box4 {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 200px;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
      border: 3px solid #0c69bf;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px black;
      width: 280px;
      height: 150px;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: none;
     }

     .quarter-box1:hover, .quarter-box2:hover,.quarter-box3:hover, .quarter-box4:hover { 
      border: 3px solid #FF9933;
     }
```

**Here's the jQuery**

```
        $('h1.issue_line').click(function(){
          $('h1.issue_line').hide("slow");
          $('ul.issue_headings').show("slow");
          $('div.quarter-box1,div.quarter-box2,div.quarter-box3,div.quarter-                 
     box4').hide("slow");
        });
        $('ul.issue_headings li.issue1').click(function(){
          $('ul.issue_headings li.issue1,div.quarter-box2,div.quarter-box3,div.quarter-

     box4').hide("slow");
          $('div.quarter-box1,ul.issue_headings li.issue2,ul.issue_headings 
     li.issue3,ul.issue_headings li.issue4').show("slow");
        });
        $('ul.issue_headings li.issue2').click(function(){
          $('ul.issue_headings li.issue2,div.quarter-box1,div.quarter-box3,div.quarter-
     box4').hide("slow");
          $('div.quarter-box2,ul.issue_headings li.issue1,ul.issue_headings 
     li.issue3,ul.issue_headings li.issue4').show("slow");
        });
        $('ul.issue_headings li.issue3').click(function(){
        $('ul.issue_headings li.issue3,div.quarter-box1,div.quarter-box2,div.quarter-          
     box4').hide("slow");
          $('div.quarter-box3,ul.issue_headings li.issue1,ul.issue_headings          
     li.issue2,ul.issue_headings li.issue4').show("slow");
        });
        $('ul.issue_headings li.issue4').click(function(){
          $('ul.issue_headings li.issue4,div.quarter-box1,div.quarter-box2,div.quarter-
     box3').hide("slow");
          $('div.quarter-box4,ul.issue_headings li.issue1,ul.issue_headings          
     li.issue2,ul.issue_headings li.issue3').show("slow");
        });
        $('div.quarter-box1').click(function(){
          $('div.quarter-box1').hide("slow");
          $('ul.issue_headings li.issue1').show("slow");
        });
      $('div.quarter-box2').click(function(){
          $('div.quarter-box2').hide("slow");
          $('ul.issue_headings li.issue2').show("slow");
        });
      $('div.quarter-box3').click(function(){
          $('div.quarter-box3').hide("slow");
          $('ul.issue_headings li.issue3').show("slow");
        });
      $('div.quarter-box4').click(function(){
          $('div.quarter-box4').hide("slow");
          $('ul.issue_headings li.issue4').show("slow");
        });
```

**Lemme know what you think!**

Comment: Interesting read http://dumitruglavan.com/jquery-performance-tips-cheat-sheet/

Comment: At first your question should be posted on `codereview.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: thanks @elclanrs for the cheat sheet.

Comment: ...and yes I know @undefined . I'm going more for functionality than aesthetics at this point - I plan to edit those later.

Comment: @sgraffito22 Sorry it's not _functional_ at all, all your codes can be rewritten in 7 or 8 lines.

Comment: ok @undefined ...how would you suggest I rewrite this in 7 or 8 lines so it's more functional?

Comment: Well okay you said that the main issue is the formatting right? Why not instead of removing the `li` element, you just remove the text inside and put the `div` instead? You can also edit the `list-style-image` to be none so it'll preserve the formatting as if it were in a list.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to start with valid html. Only `<li>` elements are supposed to be (direct) children of `<ul>` elements, but you have mixed in `<div>` elements too. The browser will do its best to cope with your invalid markup, but different browsers might handle it in different ways.

Comment: @nnnnnn already tested it on all browsers before I posted. Everything works fine. The rule is, as you said, divs can't be a  direct child, but <li> elements can have all the <div>s they want. The great thing too about "supposed to be" is you can bend the rules. Any thoughts on the question posted at the top of the page? I'm really trying to find an answer here...

Comment: @aug you might be on to something there...I'll have to play around with it. Thanks for your post!

Comment: Well my point is that even though browsers generally cope with invalid html, when you start getting problems where things aren't displaying where you expect sometimes it turns out to be the invalid html that is the problem. In your case the divs are not inside the lis. That might not be the problem at all, but I'd start by fixing it to see if it helps...

Comment: @nnnnnn aaah I see what you mean now. I thought my divs were inside the <li> elements, my bad - working on it.

Comment: Oh sweet I figured it out! Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...so based on a few suggestions from @nnnnnn and @aug, I was able to figure this out. By ensuring the HTML code was valid, the ul + div combos could be fixed (simple mistake, I completely missed it!). In addition, I added a separate h4 outside of the div, but still within the list element.

```
<div id="bottom">
<h1 class="issue_line">So what's the issue in Niagara Falls?</h1>
<ul class="issue_headings">
<li class="issue1">
    <h4>Education</h4>
    <div class="quarter-box1">
     <p>The members of NOAH recognize that <strong>quality education</strong> is necessary for any community to thrive...<br/>
     <a href="issues_taskforces.html">Read more.</a></p>
    </div>
</li>   
<li class="issue2">
    <h4>Local Hiring</h4>
    <div class="quarter-box2">
     <p>The <strong>need for jobs</strong> in Niagara County is overwhelming, and NOAH is working to create more local jobs through the policy level...<br/>
     <a href="issues_taskforces.html">Read more.</a></p>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="issue3">
    <h4>Economic Development</h4>
    <div class="quarter-box3">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et facilisis risus. Quisque a gravida urna. Ut leo ligula...<br/>
     <a href="issues_taskforces.html">Read more.</a></p>
    </div>
</li>   
<li class="issue4">
    <h4 style="margin-left:20px;">Transportation</h4>
    <div class="quarter-box4">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et facilisis risus. Quisque a gravida urna. Ut leo ligula...<br/>
     <a href="issues_taskforces.html">Read more.</a></p>
    </div>
</li>   
</ul>
</div>
```

...which then called for a few edits in the JQ:

```
$('h1.issue_line').click(function(){
     $('h1.issue_line').hide("slow");
     $('li.issue1 h4,li.issue2 h4,li.issue3 h4,li.issue4 h4').show("slow");
     $('div.quarter-box1,div.quarter-box2,div.quarter-box3,div.quarter-box4').hide("slow");
   });
   $('li.issue1 h4').click(function(){
     $('li.issue1 h4,div.quarter-box2,div.quarter-box3,div.quarter-box4').hide("slow");
     $('div.quarter-box1,li.issue2 h4,li.issue3 h4,li.issue4 h4').show("slow");
   });
   $('li.issue2 h4').click(function(){
     $('li.issue2 h4,div.quarter-box1,div.quarter-box3,div.quarter-box4').hide("slow");
     $('div.quarter-box2,li.issue1 h4,li.issue3 h4,li.issue4 h4').show("slow");
   });
   $('li.issue3 h4').click(function(){
     $('li.issue3 h4,div.quarter-box1,div.quarter-box2,div.quarter-box4').hide("slow");
     $('div.quarter-box3,li.issue1 h4,li.issue2 h4,li.issue4 h4').show("slow");
   });
   $('li.issue4 h4').click(function(){
     $('li.issue4 h4,div.quarter-box1,div.quarter-box2,div.quarter-box3').hide("slow");
     $('div.quarter-box4,li.issue1 h4,li.issue2 h4,li.issue3 h4').show("slow");
   });
   $('div.quarter-box1').click(function(){
     $('div.quarter-box1').hide("slow");
     $('li.issue1 h4').show("slow");
   });
 $('div.quarter-box2').click(function(){
     $('div.quarter-box2').hide("slow");
     $('li.issue2 h4').show("slow");
   });
 $('div.quarter-box3').click(function(){
     $('div.quarter-box3').hide("slow");
     $('li.issue3 h4').show("slow");
   });
 $('div.quarter-box4').click(function(){
     $('div.quarter-box4').hide("slow");
     $('li.issue4 h4').show("slow");
   });
```

...and lastly, a few touches in the CSS to align the list:

```
#bottom {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto; 
 clear: both;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

ul.issue_headings {
 width: 1498px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
}

ul.issue_headings li h4 {
 display: inline;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 3em;
 color: #9ac0e2;
 display:none;
 width: 350px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

ul.issue_headings li h4:hover {
 color: #FF9933;
}

.quarter-box1, .quarter-box2, .quarter-box3, .quarter-box4 { 
 float: left;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
 border: 3px solid #0c69bf;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px black;
 width: 280px;
 height: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: none;
}
```

**In conclusion, I now have a 3 stringed JQ event that can be toggled at the last phase.**

Thanks again everyone for helping to point me in the right direction!